# Best Way to Log Client-Side/Javascript in ELK (Logstash)

Tags: reactjs, logging, console, logstash, elastic-stack

We are looking to use ELK for our backend system logging. I'd also like to log the following:

- (Browser) Console tab
- (Browser) Network tab
- User Actions (we use React)

Are there any tools/add-ons/libraries that make this possible?

Answer (score 1):

At the end, you'll need a backend system to store the logged events. This backend should also be secured. You can also implement some listeners in your react app and forward the events to a endpoint of your backend in order to (optionally enrich and) forward to ELK.

Have a look on this: https://github.com/jamesjara/react-native-remote-logger and https://www.elastic.co/solutions/apm (probably not the only solution out there).